# Почему console.log(user.surname) выводит undefined?

Tags: javascript, функции, конструктор

```js
function User(name, {}) {
  this.name = name,
    this.isAdmin = false
}

let user = new User("John", {
  surname: "Smith",
  age: 27
});

console.log(user.name); //John
console.log(user.surname); //undefined
```

Comment: выполните `console.log(user)` и посмотрите, в панели разработчика, что там есть, ваш объект как "прилетел", так и "улетел", потому что на него нет никак ссылок

Comment: а где вы своему обьекту создаете свойство `surname` ?

Comment: @meine & Rostyslav Kuzmovych, так скажем тогда, я хочу просто вывести именно тот Smith. И что для этого надо сделать?

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych

Comment: @devafina вы передали обьект со своим смитом в функцию "конструктор" ничего с ним там не сделали и хочете его как-то вывести ? серьезно ?

Comment: Я проверила вывести как console.log(User.surname), console.log(User), console.log(user.User.surname) и т.д.. Почти все варианты проверила

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я хочу просто вывести именно тот Smith. И что для этого надо сделать?

---

```js
function User(name, obj = {}) {
  this.name = name,
    this.obj = obj;
  this.isAdmin = false
}

let user = new User("John", {
  surname: "Smith",
  age: 27
});

console.log(user.name); //John
console.log(user.obj.surname)
```

Comment: Вот так значит, Good! Спасибо